# Access VBA: how to return path of file you browsed to

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, filepath

I want to return the entire path of an excel file I browsed to.
Using the following,

```
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

dlg.Title = "Select Excel Spreadsheet to import"
dlg.AllowMultiSelect = False
If dlg.Show = -1 Then
    dataPath = dlg.InitialFileName
    Me!browseDataPath = dlg.InitialFileName

End If
```

I'm able to open the dialog and return the directory in which the file is located, but this code doesn't append the name of the file (e.g. blabla.xls) at the end of the path.

For example, if there is blabla.xls my C drive, it will simply return C:\

How do I get it to return C:\blabla.xls  (or whatever the name of the excel file is)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataPath = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
Me!browseDataPath = dataPath
```

As you have multi-select disabled, getting the first (one-based) item is enough.

Comment: Oh i see, so selectedItems is like an array. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
   'Paste this code in the module   

 Option Compare Database
    '***************** Code Start **************
    'This code was originally written by Ken Getz.
    'It is not to be altered or distributed,
    'except as part of an application.
    'You are free to use it in any application,
    'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
'
    ' Code courtesy of:
    ' Microsoft Access 95 How-To
    ' Ken Getz and Paul Litwin
    ' Waite Group Press, 1996

    Type tagOPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    strFilter As String
    strCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    strFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    strFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    strInitialDir As String
    strTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    strDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
    End Type
    Declare Function aht_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
     Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
    Declare Function aht_apiGetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
    Declare Function CommDlgExtendedError Lib "comdlg32.dll" () As Long
    Global Const ahtOFN_READONLY = &H1
    Global Const ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT = &H2
    Global Const ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY = &H4
    Global Const ahtOFN_NOCHANGEDIR = &H8
    Global Const ahtOFN_SHOWHELP = &H10
' You won't use these.

'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLEHOOK = &H20
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLETEMPLATE = &H40
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE = &H80

    Global Const ahtOFN_NOVALIDATE = &H100
    Global Const ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT = &H200
    Global Const ahtOFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT = &H400
    Global Const ahtOFN_PATHMUSTEXIST = &H800
    Global Const ahtOFN_FILEMUSTEXIST = &H1000
    Global Const ahtOFN_CREATEPROMPT = &H2000
    Global Const ahtOFN_SHAREAWARE = &H4000
    Global Const ahtOFN_NOREADONLYRETURN = &H8000
    Global Const ahtOFN_NOTESTFILECREATE = &H10000
    Global Const ahtOFN_NONETWORKBUTTON = &H20000
    Global Const ahtOFN_NOLONGNAMES = &H40000

' New for Windows 95

    Global Const ahtOFN_EXPLORER = &H80000
    Global Const ahtOFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS = &H100000
    Global Const ahtOFN_LONGNAMES = &H200000
    Function TestIt()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim lngFlags As Long
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Access Files (*.mda, *.mdb)", _
                    "*.MDA;*.MDB")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "dBASE Files (*.dbf)", "*.DBF")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Text Files (*.txt)", "*.TXT")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "All Files (*.*)", "*.*")
    MsgBox "You selected: " & ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:="C:\", _
        Filter:=strFilter, FilterIndex:=3, Flags:=lngFlags, _
        DialogTitle:="Hello! Open Me!")
    ' Since you passed in a variable for lngFlags,
    ' the function places the output flags value in the variable.
     Debug.Print Hex(lngFlags)
    End Function
    Function GetOpenFile(Optional varDirectory As Variant, _
    Optional varTitleForDialog As Variant) As Variant
' Here's an example that gets an Access database name.

    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim lngFlags As Long
    Dim varFileName As Variant

' Specify that the chosen file must already exist,
' don't change directories when you're done
' Also, don't bother displaying
' the read-only box. It'll only confuse people.

    lngFlags = ahtOFN_FILEMUSTEXIST Or _
                ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY Or ahtOFN_NOCHANGEDIR
    If IsMissing(varDirectory) Then
        varDirectory = ""
    End If
    If IsMissing(varTitleForDialog) Then
        varTitleForDialog = ""
    End If
    ' Define the filter string and allocate space in the "c"
    ' string Duplicate this line with changes as necessary for
    ' more file templates.
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, _
                "Access (*.mdb)", "*.MDB;*.MDA")
    ' Now actually call to get the file name.
    varFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                    OpenFile:=True, _
                    InitialDir:=varDirectory, _
                    Filter:=strFilter, _
                    Flags:=lngFlags, _
                    DialogTitle:=varTitleForDialog)
    If Not IsNull(varFileName) Then
        varFileName = TrimNull(varFileName)
    End If
    GetOpenFile = varFileName
   End Function
    Function ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
            Optional ByRef Flags As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal InitialDir As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal Filter As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal FilterIndex As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal DefaultExt As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal FileName As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal DialogTitle As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal hWnd As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal OpenFile As Variant) As Variant
' This is the entry point you'll use to call the common
' file open/save dialog. The parameters are listed
' below, and all are optional.
'
' In:
' Flags: one or more of the ahtOFN_* constants, OR'd together.
' InitialDir: the directory in which to first look
' Filter: a set of file filters, set up by calling
' AddFilterItem. See examples.
' FilterIndex: 1-based integer indicating which filter
' set to use, by default (1 if unspecified)
' DefaultExt: Extension to use if the user doesn't enter one.
' Only useful on file saves.
' FileName: Default value for the file name text box.
' DialogTitle: Title for the dialog.
' hWnd: parent window handle
' OpenFile: Boolean(True=Open File/False=Save As)
' Out:
' Return Value: Either Null or the selected filename

    Dim OFN As tagOPENFILENAME
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFileTitle As String
    Dim fResult As Boolean
    ' Give the dialog a caption title.

    If IsMissing(InitialDir) Then InitialDir = CurDir
    If IsMissing(Filter) Then Filter = ""
    If IsMissing(FilterIndex) Then FilterIndex = 1
    If IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = 0&
    If IsMissing(DefaultExt) Then DefaultExt = ""
    If IsMissing(FileName) Then FileName = ""
    If IsMissing(DialogTitle) Then DialogTitle = ""
    If IsMissing(hWnd) Then hWnd = Application.hWndAccessApp
    If IsMissing(OpenFile) Then OpenFile = True
    ' Allocate string space for the returned strings.

    strFileName = Left(FileName & String(256, 0), 256)
    strFileTitle = String(256, 0)
    ' Set up the data structure before you call the function

       With OFN
        .lStructSize = Len(OFN)
        .hwndOwner = hWnd
        .strFilter = Filter
        .nFilterIndex = FilterIndex
        .strFile = strFileName
        .nMaxFile = Len(strFileName)
        .strFileTitle = strFileTitle
        .nMaxFileTitle = Len(strFileTitle)
        .strTitle = DialogTitle
        .Flags = Flags
        .strDefExt = DefaultExt
        .strInitialDir = InitialDir
        ' Didn't think most people would want to deal with
        ' these options.
        .hInstance = 0
        '.strCustomFilter = ""
        '.nMaxCustFilter = 0
        .lpfnHook = 0
        'New for NT 4.0
        .strCustomFilter = String(255, 0)
        .nMaxCustFilter = 255
     End With
    ' This will pass the desired data structure to the
    ' Windows API, which will in turn it uses to display
    ' the Open/Save As Dialog.

    If OpenFile Then
        fResult = aht_apiGetOpenFileName(OFN)
    Else
        fResult = aht_apiGetSaveFileName(OFN)
    End If
    ' The function call filled in the strFileTitle member
    ' of the structure. You'll have to write special code
    ' to retrieve that if you're interested.
    If fResult Then
        ' You might care to check the Flags member of the
        ' structure to get information about the chosen file.
        ' In this example, if you bothered to pass in a
        ' value for Flags, we'll fill it in with the outgoing
        ' Flags value.
        If Not IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = OFN.Flags
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = TrimNull(OFN.strFile)
    Else
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
Function ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter As String, _
    strDescription As String, Optional varItem As Variant) As String
' Tack a new chunk onto the file filter.
' That is, take the old value, stick onto it the description,
' (like "Databases"), a null character, the skeleton
' (like "*.mdb;*.mda") and a final null character.
    If IsMissing(varItem) Then varItem = "*.*"
    ahtAddFilterItem = strFilter & _
                strDescription & vbNullChar & _
                varItem & vbNullChar
End Function
Private Function TrimNull(ByVal strItem As String) As String
Dim intPos As Integer
    intPos = InStr(strItem, vbNullChar)
    If intPos > 0 Then
        TrimNull = Left(strItem, intPos - 1)
    Else
        TrimNull = strItem
    End If
End Function
'************** Code End *****************


**'Now paste this part on the button click event:**

Private Sub cmd_file_Click()
 Dim s_Filter As String
    Dim s_InputFileName As String

    s_Filter = ahtAddFilterItem(s_Filter, "Excel Files (*.XLS)", "*.XLS")
    s_InputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                            Filter:=s_Filter, OpenFile:=True, _
                            DialogTitle:="Please select an input file...", _
                            Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

    Me.txt_file.Value = s_InputFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you include some actual explanation as to why this is an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in the module.

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String

Dim fldr As FileDialog
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath

    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode:

GetFolder = sItem
Sheets("Home").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing

End Function

'**And then call it by using**

Private sub button1_click()
   call GetFolder("Any default folder path")
end sub
```